# Keeping image in all forms

Tags: c#

I made 2 forms. Form2 has button which set background image. I got this :

```
this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources._29, new Size(800, 500));
//_29 is name of the picture, if you know any easier way,feel free to tell
```

How to send reference so when I set background in form2 it will set background image in all other forms and won't change until new image is chosen?

Comment: Don't ask the same question more than once.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587326/keeping-the-image-in-form-c-sharp

Comment: If you have a new, completely different question, *ask a new question*, instead of editing an old question.